# How to calculate range and variance for all the columns in a large matrix (affymetrix gene expression data) in R?

Tags: r, matrix, range, variance

[image: Affy gene expression data, probes in the column, sample name in the rows]
Hi,
I have a text file like above. I want to calculate range and variance for the all the columns (probes) and have an output file that would look hypothetically like below (Range and variance value for all the probes)-

[image]

I do not care about the rownames (containing.CEL) for this analysis. Thank you so much for your help.

Sincerely
AR

Comment: `df%>%summarise_all(list(min = min, max = max, variance = var))` . If you must have them on the same cell, `dat%>%summarise_all(list(range = ~range(.x)%>%paste0(collapse = ","), variance = var))`

Comment: I've updated my answer, It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slightly more efficient method, `matrixStats` has `colRanges` and `colVars` that work perfectly for such matrix operations:

```r
library(matrixStats)
mat <- data.matrix(df)
data.frame(Probe_ID=colnames(mat), 
           Range=colRanges(mat), 
           Variance=colVars(mat)
)
```

Comment: that was quick and easy. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `apply` function where `2` means by column

```
data.frame(
    Probe_ID = colnames(df),
    Range = apply(df,2,function(x) paste(range(x),collapse=",")),
    Variance = apply(df,2,var)
)
```

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:34,b=2:35)
```

Example Output

```
  Probe_ID Range Variance
a        a  1,34 99.16667
b        b  2,35 99.16667
```

Comment: I've Fixed this answer and added an example as proof-of-concept